# Are "How to solve in a few minutes" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-user

I have been noticing that user [JayJuly](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/476687/jayjuly) has posted multiple questions of the form:

> I am looking for the fastest way to calculate ... given only a few minutes ...

Such as [Calculate $\int_0^1\ln{(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2419400/272831)

Are these questions consider on-topic? To me, such questions seem to fall under "[mindless social fun](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)", though the line is not so cut and dry.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that the question explicitly mentions that the question is from [Integration Bee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_Bee). (At least the linked question; I did not check other posts by the same OP.) That explains the reason why they are interested also in *quick* solution. (Various users have different requirements on a post - personally, if the OP added some link to problems from such a contest where this integral is listed, that would count as sufficient context in my book.)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely doesn't seem to be mindless social fun to me. If someone were to derive fun out of finding quick solutions/approaches to math problems, it shouldn't count as mindless :) The answers to such questions should hint the approach rather than solve it completely for the user. Eg: Use trig substitution, use Laplace transform etc. That way, one can engage with the member meaningfully without solving his/her homework. Your hint in the comment seems perfectly adequate (though I can't comment on its accuracy).

Comment: My hints actually referred to the original post, which was not what the OP had intended.